# Angular ui.router: loading controller only when child view is active

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-material

In my Angular app, I have the following sample route definition which uses nested views:

```
.state('mapping.project', {
    authenticate: true,
    url: '/:projectId/:projectName',
    controller: 'ProjectCtrl as proj',
    views: {
        '': {
            templateUrl: 'app/components/mapping/partials/project.html',
            controller: 'ProjectCtrl as proj'
        },
        'details@project': {
            templateUrl: 'app/components/mapping/partials/details.html'
        },
        'activityTypes@project': {
            templateUrl: 'app/components/mapping/partials/activity-types.html'
        },
        'boundaryPartners@project': {
            templateUrl: 'app/components/mapping/partials/boundary-partners.html'
        },
        'progressMarkers@project': {
            templateUrl: 'app/components/mapping/partials/progress-markers.html'
        },
        'users@project': {
            templateUrl: 'app/components/mapping/partials/users/users.html',
            controller: 'projectUserCtrl as vm'
        }
    }
})
```

Each of these views is loaded within a tab, using Angular Material `md-tabs`: https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/directive/mdTabs

The problem is, when I access the route `mapping.project`, the `projectUserCtrl` that you can see on my `users@project` view gets immediately called. I assume the same would be true for each individual controller that I have attached to my nested views.

I'd want to call these nested controllers only when the tab is active and that particular template loaded (in this case: `users@project`).

How do I do this?

Comment: I'd go with a substate. And it could be just one, with a prameter. Switching tab will switch the state. Only one thing at time is used. And parent state could be used for Model sharing...

Comment: What's the best way of defining a bunch of child states without having to repeat myself? Is there a way to define nested child states as you do for views or do I have to define child states one by one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need all these child views, you only need 1, a container for the visible tab. Make separate states for each of the tabs, then route the child view accordingly when your "tabs" are clicked.

I'm not sure on the material design specifics, but in essence your tabs become just links ui-sref links.

Comment: Could please write up some sample code or link to an example of what you just said? I'm not sure I followed.

Comment: [Check out this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/XxFnyzjecW8JQQYZZF7L?p=preview) a great example.